# Qt debug - how to watch the value of the variable in Qt Cpp

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

Is there any way to check the value of the variable in Qt while debugging [other than calling the `printf()` or `qDebug()` function] ?

Comment: Doesn't your IDE offer you a way to watch variable values, inspect automatic variables, etc.? What IDE are you using?

Comment: No, I am using Qt Creator 2.7.0 IDE - not having option to watch a variable like visual studio.

Comment: That's because you've not followed the instructions and you haven't installed a debugger. Qt Creator offers variable watch functionality as long as you have CDB installed.

Comment: Can you kindly explain in detail what CDB or GDB, I am using  Qt Creator 2.7.0 IDE on Ubuntu 12.04 OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my understanding yes there is a way of seeing values of variables by hovering the mouse over the variables. For this you need to Enable the following option in the debugger option pane:

> Option-->Debuger-->General-->"Use tooltips in main editor while
>   debugging"

Answer (score 2):

You could use IDE(as example: QtCreator for Linux, VS for Win or even console) with integrated GDB (or other debugging tool), and set "breakpoint".

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me.

`qDebug("myVariable : %u " ,myVariable`);

Answer (score 0):

Proceed to go Debug->Add Expression Evaluator and the right side show a pane, right click and select again, "Add Expression Evaluator" option that prompt to write some expression or variable name( I use QT Creator 4.4.12)